# How can I find the actual frequency given a normalized frequency?

Tags: matlab, discrete-signals, signal-analysis, frequency-spectrum

Suppose that we have  some sample:

```
y =

   31.2241
   -5.9830
   22.6058
   -2.2309
  -42.8272
   29.2850
   -6.2652
   20.8502
   -2.4639
  -44.7525
   30.1104
   -6.0180
   21.4476
   -1.5089
  -45.1826
   29.2744
```

and somehow I know that it is obtained via a sinusoidal method which contains two sine functions at different frequencies and amplitudes, so I apply the music method:

```
pmusic(y,4)
```

and obtain the plot:

[image]

I know the location of peaks at the normalized peaks, but I don't know the actual frequency.  How can I find it?

I know the formula is $\frac{\text{normalized frequency}*f_s}{2}$, but what about $f_s$?  Can I find it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[Y,FS,NBITS]=wavread(FILE)` returns the sample rate (`FS`) in Hz and the number of bits per sample (`NBITS`) used to encode the data in the music file.

After that, `[S,F] = pmusic(Y,4,F,FS)` to compute the pseudospectrum at frequencies `F` in Hz.

Comment: but what is file?and what is inside it?

Comment: actualy i want to find frequency,not indicate myself

Comment: how do you get the original data y? You cannot get any information directly from an arbitrary given vector. I thought you sampled the data from a music file or something.

Comment: no i have some date,which is given at some frequency,but in real live should i know sampled frequency?

Comment: suppose that  that is signal coming from somewhere with additive noise,then what should i do?

Comment: so does it means that we have to know in advance some kind of information?for instance sampling frequency or something like this?if i get some vector which i know that is given at some frequency,amplitude and phase,but i dont know neither of them,i can't find them by some method?

Comment: the sampling rate is the only one you have to know in order to get the actual frequency of each point.